Carleman linearization of ode with constant term
I have started to work on a problem using Carleman linearization. I am wondering, how is this technique applied to an equation of the form
$\frac{du}{dt} = 1+u^2, u(0)=u_0$ ?
how do you treat the constant term?

The Carleman linearization is applied to systems of ODE's of the form
$${\displaystyle {\dot {x}}=f(x)+\sum _{j=1}^{m}g_{j}(x)d_{j}(t)}=:R(t,x),$$
where $x$ is a vector function of $t$ with values in $\Bbb R^d$ for some $d$. Then $R(t,x)$ gets approximated by a Taylor polynomial in $u$ (with coefficients possibly depending on $t$) and the corresponding approximation to $\frac{d}{dt}x^{[i]}$ is computed for all $i\in\Bbb N^d$, where $x^{[i]}$ is the $i$th Kronecker product.
In your case, $d=1$, $x=u$, and $R(t,x)=R(t,u)=1+u^2$, which latter is already a (Taylor) polynomial in $u$ (with coefficients not depending on $t$). So, in your case, the Carleman linearization is exact and given by the formula
$$\frac{d}{dt}u^i=iu^{i-1}(1+u^2)$$
for $i\in\Bbb N$.
